# React Native. View's style is not working, how do I fix It?

Tags: android, react-native

My app `View` `style` is not working. I`m using **react 0.44.0** with 2 emulators, however none of them is working properly. Can someone help me?
Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
    ReactNative,
    Text
} from 'react-native';

const Estilos = {
    estiloTexto: {
        fontSize: 40,
        backgroundColor: '#08509B'
    },
    estiloView: {
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
        height: 300
   }
};

//Criar o componente
const App = () => {
    const { estiloTexto, estiloView } = Estilos;
    return (
        <View sytle={{ backgroundColor: 'skyblue', height: 300 }}>
            <Text style={estiloTexto}>Frases do Dia</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

//Renderizar para o dispositivo
AppRegistry.registerComponent('app2', () => App);
```

The following should be appearing:[IOS emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Awo.png)
  But instead I get this: [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiWGT.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code

```
<View sytle={{ backgroundColor: 'skyblue', height: 300 }}>
```

Change `sytle` to `style`

Comment: OMG. I'm blind. Thanks!